# Why do Java records have accessor methods instead of public final fields?

Tags: java, java-16, java-record

[JEP-395](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) says

> a record class acquires many standard members automatically:
>
> - For each component in the header, two members: a **public accessor method with the same name** and return type as the component, and a **private final field** with the same type as the component;

If a generated final field has got the same name as the accessor method, why isn't a public final field generated instead?

Comment: There is no point in accessing your fields directly (basic fundamental of programming- encapsulation), so its just a good programming practice

Comment: If there is a public accessor method, what would be the point of making the field public? I can't make any sense out of your second question.

Comment: **Immutable data class** would not have behaviors. Why they should follow ordinary classes' convention? Personally, I think public final fields are enough.

Comment: Decades of experience disagrees with you.

Comment: And there were no pure data class in that decades of Java history.

Comment: @DonggiKim There have always existed pure data classes in Java, you just needed to take care of all the plumbing yourself instead of the compiler doing most of the work for you.

Answer (score 12):

Records can implement interfaces, so the accessor of a record could be an  implementation of an interface method. Furthermore using accessors instead of direct field access provides more flexibility, for example you can replace an accessor that directly returns a field with an accessor that derives a value in some way (or vice versa).

Records also allow you to override accessors to - instead of just plainly returning the field - do something extra. Making records use direct field access would restrict and limit what you could do with records, and thus limit their usefulness, while having accessors offers you the baseline offered by direct field access with the ability to do more if necessary.

To quote an example provided by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) in the comments:

> the classes `public record R(int a, int b) { public int c() { return …; }}` and `public record R(int a, int c) { public int b() { return …; }}` provide the same API, regardless of their internal representation.

In short, generating accessors for fields offers more flexibility and features than direct field access. The same also applies to plain immutable classes.

Another reason is provided by [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66704373/466862):

> Without the ability to override accessors, records would be unable to
> properly support mutable objects (such as arrays) as components. If
> you have an array component, you may want to perform a defensive copy
> in the constructor and accessor (which would also require overriding
> equals, in order to preserve the specification of Record); if it was a
> public final field, you could not encapsulate the mutability of your
> components

Comment: Does not overriding accessor make the method counter-intuitive? It will make programmers have inconsistent assumption about record's accessors. Why the accessor with the same name of the final field could do that?

Comment: @DonggiKim Why would it? The fact accessors are methods simply offers you more flexibility than the straight-jacket of direct fields access. You don't have to use the fact you can explicitly implement the accessor (and in most cases you probably shouldn't use it), but if you need to, you can. You can also use it for evolution of a record, for example, add a field that was previously calculated, or split something that used to be a single field into multiple fields, but then add a method to replace the accessor, ensuring binary compatibility, etc.

Comment: @DonggiKim the motivation for encapsulation is the same as for other, non-record classes. E.g., the classes `public record R(int a, int b) { public int c() { return …; }}` and `public record R(int a, int c) { public int b() { return …; }}` provide the same API, regardless of their internal representation.

Answer (score 5):

I think a key factor in this decision was that you now have the ability to *override* the Record's getters:

```
public record MyRecord(String myProperty) {
    @Override
    public String myProperty() {
        return "The property is " + myProperty;
    }
}
```

Something like this would not be possible with public final fields.

Comment: Should an immutable data class has to have such methods(behavior)?
I don't think Introducing record is for just add some syntax sugars.

Comment: Without the ability to override accessors, records would be unable to properly support mutable objects (such as arrays) as components.  If you have an array component, you may want to perform a defensive copy in the constructor and accessor (which would also require overriding `equals`, in order to preserve the specification of `Record`); if it was a public final field, you could not encapsulate the mutability of your components.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally best practice to use accessor methods instead of direct field access.  Even with records, it makes sense to continue that practice to allow for, say, renaming your fields without breaking existing code.

Comment: But is not **immutable data class** have different purpose to ordinary classes which have their own specific behaviour?

Comment: In most cases migrating to Records from POJOs with getters _will_ break relying code, as Record accessors are in the form `myProperty()` instead of `getMyProperty()`.

Comment: @DonggiKim: No.  Many -- maybe even most -- of your classes should already be immutable data-holding classes.

Answer (score -4):

Java programmers are absolutely *addicted* to needless encapsulators. They look at a public final field and recoil in superstitious revulsion. So we get people making crazed knee-jerk statements like "There is no point in accessing your fields directly (basic fundamental of programming- encapsulation)", together with kooky reasoning that it is sound to mandate a naming convention (get/set and *bizarrely* is) as the *only* correct way to address a datum - despite the fact that you have no idea what those method implementations *actually* do.

Of course, the reason it persists it because of the language's *baffling* decision to not implement properties as a built-in feature of the language (a la C#, Kotlin) at any point in the past 30 years. Instead, spending a decade making repeated abortive attempts at modularization of the language (a practically unused feature since it finally arrived).

The introduction of Records would have been the perfect opportunity to implement properties properly once and for all (it's a pifflingly simple enhancement, after all - implement it in the desugar pass of the compiler and it's a day's work, I've done it myself; another couple of days to add property listener support to all accessible fields). But still, no.

So, rant over, back to the question. Public final fields would have been a more sensible implementation, with an *option* to make the field private (`record R (private int foo, int bar)`) where encapsulation was absolutely required. Better yet, automatic wrapping of collections/maps in immutable decorators could have been implemented easily (declare `List` and the auto-generated constructor ensures the field receives an immutable `List`), removing the only compelling argument for auto-encapsulating an immutable POJO  field.

But it would have run contrary to a (faulty) prejudice against public final fields which is endemic in the Java community.

Comment: I suspect this has received downvotes as rants are discouraged here, by virtue of the fact that technical writing is encouraged. Readers may also be wondering if you're holding these views rather too strongly, to the degree you're unduly upset. If you can soften the edges of the wording, that might help.